# Optional Async Pipe Or Default

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe

I didn't find the better way how to read default value if  observable value is undefined.
Instead of writing this part of code for each observable property within template

```
            <div *ngIf="!property.visible$
              ? property.visible || true
              : (property.visible$ | async">Test</div>
```

Can be here the shortest way to do it?

Currently am looking for possibility writing a customPipe to do the same work but seems like it's really difficult to extend an async Pipe for the purpose to have this template

```
property.visible$ | async: property.visible || true
```

Or may you have other ideas ?

Note:

Also it's possible to write a function with this logic  in the ts file but don't think it will be a good idea for performance to take(1) subscribe value each time while html is updated and we need to read an observable value

Comment: `https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-async-pipe `  may be this is your case..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use this extension async pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({ name: 'default$' })
export class Default$Pipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(
    value$: Observable<any> | undefined,
    defaultValue: any
  ): Observable<any> {
    return value$ ? value$ : of(defaultValue);
  }
} 

 property.visible$| default$ : property.visible || false | async
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own observable and then susbscribe to it with `async` pipe:

```
this.visible$ = of({}).pipe(switchMap(() => {
 if (this.property.visible$) return this.property.visible$;

 return of(this.property.visible);
}));
```

...

```
<div *ngIf="visible$ | async"></div>
```

Please take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knj6uj)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can wrap the command in the bracket and add a default like below

```
(property.visible$ | async) || true
```